# SPARCstation 1+ cache block size

Tags: sparc64

What is the size of each cache block in a SPARCstation 1+?

The only information I found about the cache was that it is "64K write-through cache, direct-mapped, virtually indexed, virtually tagged, 16-byte lines; 50ns cycle"

I'm assuming that, since it's direct-mapped, the size of the block can be calculated by dividing the size of the cache by the size of the lines, which would be 65536 / 16 = 4096 Bytes = 4K
Is this correct?

Also, how would one determine it's L1 cache miss penalty time?

Comment: There's a datasheet for the processor in your machine [here](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=39103eef3f832260012cb4cfc1ff7d7f01c5d6&type=M&term=L64801). However, it doesn't include the information you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks @Jules! That might be helpful for my next steps. Meanwhile, I've been able to confirm that @lvd's answer is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"line" is exactly the cache block size you are asking about. So it had 4096 blocks of 16 bytes each.